# FormContentDisplayDriver thrown from BuildDisplayAsync by InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022, orchardcore

good morning i have this problem in side of server, in the log show me this problem , but i can't find where should i fix it, i'm building my project whit dll modules of OrchardCore.

Category: OrchardCore.ContentManagement.Display.ContentItemDisplayCoordinator

FormContentDisplayDriver thrown from BuildDisplayAsync by `InvalidOperationException`

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operations that change
> non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent
> update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The
> collection's state is no longer correct.    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.FindValue(TKey key)    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue&
> value)    at
> OrchardCore.ContentManagement.ContentExtensions.Get(ContentElement
> contentElement, Type contentElementType, String name)    at
> OrchardCore.ContentManagement.ContentExtensions.Get[TElement](ContentElement
> contentElement, String name)    at
> OrchardCore.Forms.Drivers.FormContentDisplayDriver.DisplayAsync(ContentItem
> model, BuildDisplayContext context)    at
> OrchardCore.ContentManagement.Display.ContentItemDisplayCoordinator.BuildDisplayAsync(ContentItem
> contentItem, BuildDisplayContext context)

good morning i have this problem in side of server, in the log show me this problem , but i can't find where should i fix it, i'm building my project whit dll modules of OrchardCore.